# Capture results between delimiters. Content may contain a delimiter character

Tags: regex

I have the following reg exp: `/@\w+(\(((?:(?!\))\S|\s)*)\))?/m`

And the value I'm expecting are template files like:

```
@for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {{ $i }}
@endfor

@if(
    !empty($name)
    && $name == 'Carlos'
)
    Hi Carlos
@endif

@csfr
```

I'm having trouble capturing the full content from @if parenthesis.

The expected result would be:

```
!empty($name)
&& $name == 'Carlos'
```

But it returns this instead because of the closing parenthesis from the `empty` function:

```
!empty($name
```

How to capture the full expression, since this could contain calls to other functions?

Regexp debug link: https://regex101.com/r/58ZbXe/1

Comment: See `@\w+(\(((?:[^()]++|(\g<1>))*)\))?` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/58ZbXe/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just as expected! Genius

Comment: @carlos What do you want to match from the `@for`?

Comment: @Bohemian `$i = 0; $i < 10; $i++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
@\w+(\(((?:[^()]++|(\g<1>))*)\))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/58ZbXe/2).

*Details*:

- `@` - a `@` char
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(\(((?:[^()]++|(\g<1>))*)\))?` - Group 1 (optional):

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `((?:[^()]++|(\g<1>))*)` - Group 2:

    - `(?:[^()]++|(\g<1>))*` - zero or more repetitions of either one or more chars other than `(` and `)` or Group 1 pattern
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 2):

This is the shortest regex I could think of:

```
@\w+\(((\(.*?\)|.)*?)\)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/rCbZPJ3rBfog4).

Use the DOTALL flag and your target is in group 1.

This works by matching either bracketed content or dot within the brackets.

---

If you need the leading newline trimmed from the `@if` contents:

```
@\w+\(\n?((\(.*?\)|.)*?)\)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/FaODyzTrm9JRlA).

Comment: This works fine with single lines but for some reason it stops capturing the other functions

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/GLNPPp/1

Comment: @CarlosCarucce as I said, you need the DOTALL flag set, which you did not set in your regex101 demo. You had multi line set, not single line. See https://regex101.com/r/d3jSrM/1 or https://regex101.com/r/JARnK4/1 if you want the leading newline trimmed from the `@if` block

Comment: Missed flag explanation at first. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex:

```
@(?<begin>[A-Za-z]+)\((?<content>[^@]*)\)[^@]+@(?<end>end\1)
```

Explanation:

- `@`: @
- `(?<begin>[A-Za-z]+)`: Group 1 (begin tag)

  - `[A-Za-z]+`: any combination of alphabetical character
- `\(`: open parenthesis
- `(?<content>[^@]*)`: Group 2 (content of parenthesis)

  - `[^@]*`: any character other than @
- `\)`: closed parenthesis
- `[^@]+`: any character other than @
- `@`: @
- `(?<end>end\1)`: Group 3 (end tag)

  - `@`: @
  - `end`: end
  - `\1`: content from first group

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rwISf7/1).

Comment: `([^@]|\n)*` is basically the same as `[^@]*`. And please never use `(.|\n)*`. There are almost always alternatives to this awful construct.

Comment: This one even matches the contents! Thanks a lot! This will be useful for sure. But I will have to give the accepted to Wiktor's answer because he aswered the initial question first

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for pointing out. Initially it was just `.*`, then with some updates I forgot to clean it. Why do you think this is awful?